# While trying to run Entity Framework API in swagger

Tags: .net, api, entity-framework

> System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure' to the 'UseSqlServer' call.
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (233): No process is on the other end of the pipe.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

I'm not able to get a response from the API.

Answer (score 0):

In this error we need to add  trustServerCertificate = true in our connection string
so in my case name of connection string is like that
"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ToDoList;Integrated Security = true; trustServerCertificate = true"